# Как работает оператор присваивания c типом boolean в Java?

Tags: java, логика

Есть код.

```
  public class IfElseTest {
    public static void main(String...args) {
      boolean b = false;
      if (b == false) {
        System.out.println(b=false);
      }

      if (b = false) {
        System.out.println("if statement");
      } else {
        System.out.println("else statement");
      }
    }
  }
```

На выходе эта программа даёт:

- false
- else statement

И неясно, почему выражение в пятой строчке   `System.out.println(b=false);`компилятор толкует как ***false***. Хотя интуитивно ясно, что если ***b*** был ложь, то ***b*** присвоить ложь должно быть ***true.***

Вопрос: почему b = false компилятор воспринимает как false?

Comment: О прикольно. Отошел на 5 минут по нужде, прихожу, бац - пять ответов. Спасибо, коллеги! Всем печеньки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хорошее форматирование кода помогает лучше его понять.:) Поэтому я запишу код в следующем виде

```
boolean b = false;

if (b == false)
    System.out.println(b=false);

if (b = false)
    System.out.println("if statement");
else
    System.out.println("else statement");
```

В первом if-предложении

```
if (b == false)
    System.out.println(b=false);
```

переменная `b` **сравнивается** с литералом `false`, и так как эта переменная была инициализирована этим же значением

```
boolean b = false;
```

то очевидно результат вычисления выражения if-предложения, то есть **результат сравнения**, является истина. Поэтому на консоль выводится

```
    System.out.println(b=false);
```

Во втором if-else-предложении

```
if (b = false)
    System.out.println("if statement");
else
    System.out.println("else statement");
```

в условии if переменной `b` `присваивается` значение false

```
if (b = false)
```

результатом этого выражения, то есть **присваивания**,  является результат присваивания**. Так как результат равен false, то кодовый блок после if-предложения не будет выполнен, а управление перейдет на предложение с else

```
else
    System.out.println("else statement");
```

и, соответственно на консоль будет выдано

```
    System.out.println("else statement");
```

Если сравнить эти два if-предложения

```
if (b == false)
if (b = false)
```

то в первом if-предложении значением выражения является результат сравнения. Так как **false**  (то есть b)  равно самому себе, то результат сравнения истина.
Во-втором if-предложении значением выражения является результат присваивания переменной b значения **false**, то есть значение выражения if-предложения есть **false**.

Вы могли бы переписать второе if-предложение следующим образом

```
if (( b = false) == false )
```

и тогда, фактически, оно стало бы эквивалентно предложениям из начала программы

```
boolean b = false;

if (b == false)
```

И вы бы получили тот же самый результат, что и в первом if-предложении, так как значением выражения стало не присвоенное значение переменной b, а результат сравнения.

Answer (score 5):

Не могу сказать умных слов. Но интуитивно понятно, что `System.out.println(b=false);` это эквивалент

```
b=false;
System.out.println(b);
```

Т.е. сначала обрабатывается операция присваивания, а потом выводится значение переменной. Т.е. само по себе присваивание не является булевой операцией.

Можете ради интереса проверить с другими типами, по идее должно вывести `10`:

```
int a=5;
System.out.println(a = 10);
```

PS не относится непосредственно к делу, но я бы рекомендовал поправить форматирование, а то у меня есть предположение, судя по Вашим отступам, что Вы в целом можете еще и немного неправильно интерпретировать операции, которые выполняются в случае выполнения первого условия.

Comment: Ну допустим вы правы. System.out.println(b=false); Равносильно 
b=false;
System.out.println(b); 
Почему тогда  System.out.println(b==false) вернёт true?

Comment: @AndrewKachalin да потому что `(b==false)?`->да, это истинна->`System.out.println(true);`

Comment: Результат присваивания - значение самой переменной: `a = 10` "вернет" `10` независимо от значения `a`.
А результат булевого оператора - это булевое значение: `a == 10`, вернет `true` или `false` в зависимости от значения `a`.
Можете проверить такой результат `System.out.println(b = b == false)`, это либо запутает Вас еще сильнее, либо позволит прояснить немного ситуацию =)

Answer (score 1):

В первом случае вы же сравниваете переменную с константой и для компилятора не показатель что они булевского типа - результат отдаётся для оператора "==".

А в строчке:

```
   if (b = false) {}
```

компилятор использует для ветвления булевскую переменную, заодно присваивая ей значение. Это равносильно записи:

```
   b = false;
   if (b) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

> почему b = false компилятор воспринимает как false?

потому что сначала:

- выполняется присваивание переменной `b` значения `false`;
- потом для этой же переменной [вызывается](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html) метод `toString()`.

> Invoking print or println outputs a single value after converting the value using the appropriate toString method

Answer (score 1):

> почему b = false компилятор воспринимает как false?

Дело в том, что вы используете не операцию сравнения в операторе `if`, которая записывается как `==`, а производите операцию присваивания `=` (вычисляете выражение) в проверке условия `if`

То есть, в этом случае не проверяется равно ли `b` `false`, а производится вычисление выражения, в котором `b` присваивается значение `false` и естественно, что компилятор его так и воспринимает, потому что в результате операции `b = false` ее результат будет `false`